# How to choose values for min_samples_leaf and min_samples_split while training the decision tree on our dataset

Tags: decision-tree

I have a question of : Generate a list of 10 values of each for the parameters min_samples_split and min_samples_leaf. And select the value which is best for predicting accuracy of the model.
I know selecting min value for min_samples_split will lead to overfitting of the model and large values will result in inadequate training. 
What should be the range of values I should ideally compare as compared to the length of my dataset. Length of my dataset - 39859 
Thanks in advance.